# exec в php не выводит ответ

Tags: php, shell, exec

```
$output = array();
exec("123" , $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Что выводится в командной строке:

```
-bash: 123: command not found
```

Что выводит скрипт:

```
string(0) "" array(0) { }
```

При этом базовая команда в php

```
echo exec('pwd');
```

Работает нормально. Как получать ответы?

Мне необходимо через php запускать в консоли Appimage, и получать все ответы, в том числе ошибочные и неудачные

Comment: `exec — Выполнить внешнюю программу` у вас есть внешняя программа с названием 123?

Comment: У меня есть внешняя программа, которая не вызывается, поэтому я пробую получить хоть какой-то ответ. А из консоли та же команда - внешняя программа - вызывается

Comment: -bash: 123: команда не найдена, передается в потоке stderr, для того что бы перехватить эту ошибку, нужно перевести потоко stderr в stdout, т.е. добавить 2>&1, к примеру в терминале вводим команды: `a=$(123); ` - переменная $a будет пустой, но если выполнить `a=$(123 2>&1);` в переменную $a запишется строка `-bash: 123: команда не найдена`

Comment: Писать вывод в файл, а потом уже файл стандартными средствами PHP считывать. А в целом, вызывать shell из PHP - плохая идея. Особенно пользовательский ввод. Просто замечание.